# Unwanted automatic scrolling with UIScrollView and UITextFields as subviews

Tags: iphone, scroll, uiscrollview, uitextfield, first-responder

**The "too long; didn't read" version: *Is there any way to disable the automatic scrolling behaviour of `UIScrollView` when telling a `UITextField` to `becomeFirstResponder`?***

I have a scroll view with paging enabled and several views as subviews, each subview being controlled by its own view controller. Each subview has a UITextField.

The requirement is that when a page is scrolled into view, it's text field should become first responder.

This is fine when using finger swipes to scroll -- I use the scroll view delegate method `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` to know when scrolling stops and a page is in view, I can tell the text field to become first responder.

However, when the scroll view is "autoscrolled", as in when telling the scrollview to `scrollRectToVisible:animated:`, the scroll view delegate method for deceleration isn't called. I use this method when scrolling newly created pages into view without the user's interation, or when the user taps the `UIPageControl`.

My solution was to simply set the first responder status of the text field before telling it to scroll into view - but it seems that telling a text field that is in a scroll view to become first responder causes the scroll view to automatically scroll it into view.

I assume this is behaviour used when putting text fields in table view cells (since table views are scroll view subclasses). If you set up a small test app, with a table view, and a text field within a table cell, if the keyboard would obscure the table view cell when it becomes first responder, the table view will automatically scroll it to be visible.

I don't understand, though, why this behaviour occurs in my example, where I'm not using a table view - just a plain scroll view.

I should also mention that my scroll view has vertical scrolling disabled and only scrolls horizontally.

I have tested in another test app that puts text fields as direct subviews of a scrollview (no view controllers or container views) and the same happens. If you tell a text field that is offscreen to become first responder, the scroll view with automatically scroll it for you.

This wouldn't normally be a problem, but it seems to screw up the paging of the scroll view. When I scroll with my finger, each view bounces and is centred properly. But when I scroll a rect to be visible *with animation* and tell a text field to become first responder, scroll view seems to become conflicted with itself and the view is only scrolled part of the way into view, and isn't centred.

Then, if I touch a view using my finger (not swipe, or even move), the scroll view jumps back to the first page.

My current work around for all this silly auto scrolling behaviour is to use an `NSTimer` to determine when to update the first responder.

I do the manual scrolling in code using `scrollRectToVisible:animated` and then after 0.3 seconds, call my method to update the text field to be first responder. (0.3 seconds was trial and error, trying to see which seemed to be the smallest amount of time to allow for the animation but still be long enough not to cause the conflict with the scrollview.

As you can see, this isn't elegant, and is likely to break.

**Is there any way to disable the automatic scrolling behaviour of `UIScrollView` when telling a `UITextField` to `becomeFirstResponder`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer to your question, but it should fix the problem:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
  // Make the text field first responder...
}
```

Comment: I did look into this method after I posted my question. Initially I thought it would fix the issue, so I removed my timer code, and put the firstrResponder business in this method. But when you tap the page control repeatedly and quickly, the scroll view jumps around eratically, because there's not a long enough delay between the animation stopping and the text field being told to become first responder... Sadly, the timer does a better job.

Answer (score 7):

Call becomeFirstResponder, then right away, set the contentOffset of the scrollview to its current position..

```
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
[scrollview setContentOffset:scrollview.contentOffset animated:NO];
```

Comment: It's working also if you call setContentOffset on a tableview overriding the becomeFirstResponder method from the textfield

Comment: sometimes it works, but not for the cell on the top in tableView

Comment: For me it works in a collection view except for the first cell. Let's see if some find a complete solution, for now that's better than nothing.